# Query long "statistics" step solved by using temp table, why?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have this query (4.8 seconds run time):

```
SELECT  a, b, c
    FROM  table_a ta
    INNER JOIN  table_b tb  ON ta.id = tb.id
      AND  ta.id2 = tb.id2
    WHERE  ta.id2 = 1
      AND  tb.id2 = 1
      AND  ta.id IN (*100K strings list*)
```

(I know the condition on id2 = 1 can be done better, lets ignore that for now)

So for the above query, when profiling, I get:

| statistics           | 3.471655 |

Reading online a bit, I saw it meant the thread is performing "disk-bound other work".

After changing the query to insert the 100K strings into a temp table and joining with that table, I managed to reduce the run time to 0.82 
seconds, but I cant say I completely understand why.

So:

1. What does "disk bound other-work" mean exactly? What determines how long this step will run? Table size row-wise? Table size bytes-wise?
2. Where does that run time improvement comes from? Is JOIN really that much more efficient than IN? I always figured they just create some hash set in memory and use that, which should be very fast

EDIT:
Im using MariaDB 10.2.25.

CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  d VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  e VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  f VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  g VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  h VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  i VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  a CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  j CHAR(32),
  k CHAR(27) NOT NULL,
  id BIGINT(20),
  l VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  m VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  n VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  o TEXT,
  b INT DEFAULT NULL,
  p VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  q INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  r INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  s INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  t CHAR(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  u INT(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  v BOOL,
  w BOOL,
  x BOOL,
  y VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  z VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  dd VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  ee VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  ff VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  gg VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  hh VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  ii VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  jj BOOL DEFAULT NULL,
  kk VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  id2 INT NOT NULL,
  ll INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY idx1 (m),
  KEY idx2 (id2,id),
  KEY idx3 (id2),
  PRIMARY KEY (id2,a)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE table_b (
   aaa CHAR(27) NOT NULL,
   id BIGINT(20),
   bbb INT UNSIGNED,
   c INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   ccc VARCHAR(50),
   id2 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   KEY idx1 (id2,id),
   PRIMARY KEY (id2,aaa),
   KEY `id` (`id`)
);
```

EXPLAIN
Query 1:

```
+------+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                    | key         | key_len | ref                       | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table_a | range | PRIMARY,idx3,idx2               | PRIMARY     | 100     | NULL                      | 100000 | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table_b | ref   | PRIMARY,id                     | id         | 13      | table_a.id,const           |      1 |             |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+-------------+
```

EXPLAIN Query 2:

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                    | key         | key_len | ref                       | rows  | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ttt   | index  | PRIMARY                          | PRIMARY     | 62      | NULL                      | 76191 | Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table_a | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx3,idx2             | PRIMARY     | 100     | const,ttt.id              |     1 | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table_b | ref    | PRIMARY,id                     | id        | 13      | table_a.id,const            |     1 |             |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables and `EXPLAIN SELECT...` for both selects.  The answer may be in those things.  Also, what version of MySQL/MariaDB -- optimizations have changed in these areas.

Comment: @RickJames added

Answer (score 0):

(Too much for a Comment; may lead to an Answer.)

- `CHAR(32)` -- are these UUIDs?  If so, declare them `CHARACTER SET ascii`, not utf8.
- Be consistent on `SIGNED` vs `UNSIGNED`, especially with columns used in `JOIN`.
- `id         | 13      | table_a.id,const` does not agree with the table definition given.  Please fix.
- How much time does it take to build `ttt`?  If that is too large, you are not saving any time.

Comment: No UUIDs. OK about the JOIN but Its besides the point for my questions right?.   Im not sure what to tell you... im looking at the explain now and thats what it says about the id and 13 part.   Right, I missed that, table creation takes takes 0.4 so overall its 1.22 seconds which is still good but that most important part I think is that its not disk-bound (at least from what I gather) which looks to be the problem since we get a timeout for that query every once in a while even though we have a 30 seconds timeout

Comment: Im guessing the data above is needed more for question 2 (correct me if im wrong), are you able to answer question 1? Feels to me (maybe im wrong) that question 1 is really more general and the answer to it is related to the specific tables/query since "statistics" mean the same for every query/table right?

Comment: @TheDarkLord - MD5 or other hash?  What do you have in CHAR(32)?

Comment: @TheDarkLord - "timeout every once in a while" -- Probably the data has been bumped out of cache (the buffer_pool), thereby necessitating a slow fetch from disk.  In cache versus on disk is typically a 10:1 speed difference.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Key_len = 13 means that the column(s) used in the index add up to 13 bytes.  `id` is `BIGINT` (8 bytes), but then what is the other 5?  I'm suggesting that `KEY id (...)` was not obfuscated correctly.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - When timing, run the query twice; take the second time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198334/discussion-between-thedarklord-and-rick-james).